# How to change localhost to custom url for a project in visual studio?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, localhost, outlook-addin

I am working on Outlook Web Addin (OWA) project and downloaded a sample project from internet that is just showing basic information of selected email. The email information is showing in a .html page and this .html page is showing in iFrame of OWA. Till this point everything is good and I can see the details and everything is handled by the project itself that I downloaded.

Now our main requirement is when user clicks on "Inbox" then I need to capture that event and do something. But the problem I am facing is the OWA is running in different domain and my .html page that is running using Visual Studio is running in different domain. I don't have control over OWA and if iFrame page and main page both are not in same domain then I can't execute my JS code for parent page elements.

OWA URL: https://inexyz.customdomain.com/owa/#path=/mail

iFrame url: https://localhost:12345/messageread.html

The problem I am facing is how can I run my AddIn project incustomdomain.com. If I host it on local IIS then while debugging how can I append my messageread.html page url to iframe? Is there any way to change localhost:12345 to customdomain.com while debuggin using visual studio.

To resolve the above problem I tried to change the project URL in Visual Studio. I've checked checkbox for "Override application root URL" and set custom url like "https://machinename.customdomain.com/messageread.html" and instead of "IIS Express" set "Local IIS", also created vistural directory for the same. If I try to brows the messageread.html page using virtual directory it's working fine but when I try to run solution (Web Addin project) it's showing "Deployment error" and in Error List window it shows nothing.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Exchange server 2013.

OS: Windows 10.

IIS: 10

Anyone any idea, how can I change project URL from visual studio instead of localhost:prot?

Comment: You mean that you want the get the DOM of the outlook window instead of your add-in and then control the clicking of open a message? or what exactly ? ...

Comment: what exactly I want is when user right clicks and open context menu I want to add some custom options in then context menu. But the problem is I don't have control over outlook because that is being managed by someone else so I want to perform adding new items in context menu using iframe page. Hope I am clear this time.